# Running Detox Tests during CI

Tags: detox

The question is fairly simple, we'd like to get Detox running as part of our CI pipeline in GitHub. We've tried a few things:

- Running in AppCentre
- Running in a GitHub Action

We've hit problems with both of these. Firstly that our iOS detox release build seems to take ages, over 60 minutes (before the tests even run) which exceeds the maximum timeout for AppCentre.

GitHub doesn't seem to be able to run an emulator on the Ubuntu image, so we've done so on the macOS image. This burns through build minutes like anything (which isn't the biggest problem) but we've also found inconsistencies with the test run compared to local which makes things really hard to debug. I think the mix of issues we've had here makes us want to try an do something more SaaS based.

At the moment most of our CI is done via GitHub actions, we do have a jenkins server that may be an option, we don't currently have any macOS devices to use as a runner - but it's an option I'm exploring.

Has anyone found a good way of running Detox tests in a pipeline, or via a provider and if so how did you achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am able to do that from jenkins - appcenter

Comment: This provides no help at all, please provide a script / setup / or details on how you achieved this.

Answer (score 0):

@sainqdh reddy I would be curious see/learn more about your Jenkins pipeline/Detox-e2e job. We’re running detox
Tests in Jenkins as well, but the builds are incredibly slow and trying
To run multiple specs in parallel typically turns into a
Flakey nightmare.